# converting int to hh:mm format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have separate integers for hours and minutes and i need to find a way to get the total number of hours followed by minutes preferably in a HH:MM format. The issue that i'm facing is when the minutes are less than ten there is no leading zero and i am doing this for reporting reasons and so would love to be able to do something like

Total Hours worked

102:06      to represent 102 hours and 6 minutes

```
DECLARE @hours INT  = 102
declare @minutes int = 6

SELECT
 CONCAT(CAST (SUM((@hours*60)+@minutes)/60 AS VARCHAR(5)) , ':' , CAST (SUM((@hours*60)+@minutes)%60 AS VARCHAR(2)))
```

Comment: "_102_:06 to represent _106_ hours and 6 minutes"?!?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Your code is product specific.)

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in SQL ?  Your post looks wrong, how does 102:06 translate into 106 hours and 6 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you can do:

```
select concat(hours, ':',
              right('00' + minutes, 2)
             )
```

Another method would be:

```
select concat(hours, ':',
              right(convert(varchar(255), 100 + minutes), 2)
             )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another similar option using format()

**Example**

```
DECLARE @hours INT  = 102
declare @minutes int = 6

Select concat(@hours,format(@minutes,':00'))
```

**Returns**

```
102:06
```